# Ask the user to send crash log after crash on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, logging, crash, send

Some application ask the user if they want to send the crash log by email when they restart after a crash. How are they doing that ?

They have to record the log when they crashing and reads this file and ask the user to send it if it's not empty ?

Is there a framework or an open source project I can integrate to do this ?

Comment: I just discover http://hoptoadapp.com/pages/ios-notifier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [PLCrashReporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/).

Answer (score 6):

Check out Crittercism ([www.crittercism.com](http://www.crittercism.com)), I've been using it for feedback and crash reporting for my ios and android apps.

Comment: I used crittercism for awhile and liked it but now alot of their features are broken and their support seems to suck when it comes to fixing those issues. Right now their feedback doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one although I have not used it so I can not give an opinion on how well it works.
[Crashkit](http://parveenkaler.com/2010/08/11/crashkit-helping-your-iphone-apps-suck-less/)